# Parametrized probability density (Bayesian Inference)

Tags: probability, bayesian, density-function

Quite often, when I read some text where density parameters are used, some special rules apply. Example:

[image: Pattern Recognition]

The $x$ is a random vector drawn from the same distribution as samples in $X$. I understand, that they use law of total probability, but I arrive at something slightly different:

$$
p(x|X)
=\int p(x,\theta|X) d\theta
=\int \frac{p(x,\theta,X)}{p(X)} d\theta
=\int \frac{p(x|\theta,X)p(\theta,X)}{p(X)} d\theta
=\int p(x|X,\theta) p(\theta|X)d\theta
$$

For me, $\theta$ is just a random variable. I don't understand these special rules. I've never read a proper introduction about such parametrised densities. Would you please explain to me why am I free to omit $X$ in the condition as they did in the picture above? Would you please recommend me some articles, books, anything, that'll help me understand it?

Thank you.

Comment: You have not told us what $x$ is, but presumably  $ p(x\mid \theta)=p(x\mid X,\theta)$ for all foreseeable $X$.  For example if $X$ was a set of $n$ previous samples from an exponential distribution with rate $\theta$ then you would not expect some future observation $x$ to depend on the past $X$ except to the extent that having seen $X$ affects your belief about the distribution of $\theta$

Comment: I can see how $x$ is independent of $X$ given $\theta$. But $X$ and $\theta$ are dependent, $p(\theta,X) \neq p(\theta)p(X)$, so I don't see any way how to simplify it to what's presented in the book. (I updated the question w.r.t. $x$).

Comment: If $x$ is independent of $X$ given $\theta$ then $p(x\mid \theta)=p(x\mid X,\theta)$ and so your calculation and the book give the same result

Comment: That is an answer, @Henry.  You should post it as such, so woky can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is **Conditional Independence**. The [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) links to [great answers on this site](http://great%20answers%20on%20this%20site). My case is probably similar to [biased coin tossing example](https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~norman/BBNs/Independence_and_conditional_independence.htm).

Bob tosses the coin and gets heads. Since I had no knowledge about the coin, I can now assume that the coin is slightly biased towards heads. If Alice tosses the same coin after Bob, then $P(A=H|B=H) > P(A=H)$. But if I had the information (event $C$) that the coin is biased towards heads, then $$P(A=H|B=H,C) = P(A=H|C) > P(A=H).$$ Given $C$, event $B=H$ doesn't change the likelihood of event $A=H$ (I already know the coin is biased from $C$. But can results of Bob affect my belief in $C$?).

Same goes for my vectors $x$ and $X$. Given previous samples $X$, I can assume the likelihood of vector $x$. But once I have the parameter of the distribution $\theta$, previous samples $X$ give no additional information over $\theta$ on the likelihood of $x$. So
$$
p(x|\theta,X) = p(x|\theta).
$$

I'm not familiar with this concept and I've never encountered it in my probability courses or in other texts that use probability (not even in appendices where probability basics are introduced). Everyone seems to tacitly assume that everyone understands it. It's obvious when explained like in articles above.